# Jira plugin - How to pass a very long string to velocity template from a Jira plugin

Tags: templates, plugins, jira, velocity

I'm building a Jira plugin that displays some stuff regarding project issues in a velocity page.
So I've used the getContextMap method and put in the map my result string that I'm parsing on the velocity page something like:

contextMap.put("myvariable", verylongstring);

Unfortunately I can see that the length of the string I can pass to the map is limited. Is there a solution to this - i.e. passing a very long string to velocity template?

Thanks
Ed

Comment: How can you tell that the length of string is limited? And what are you calling getContextMap on?

Comment: Thanks for a reply. My string is quite long - about 3k characters. I see that it is cut in the velocity template when in javascript I get it via var myString = '$mylongstring'; It is cut somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Oh, and the getContextMap is the method where I do my logic of plugin when a button is pressed on the Project page.

Comment: I'm changing my code now to put a serialized Json string to that variable instead of custom-coded string. Maybe this will help. I'll update here once it is done

Comment: Can you add some code and an atlassian-plugin.xml which illustrates the problem to your question?

Comment: Also, which version of Jira?

Comment: Thanks to all guys. It was just my bug that I didn't catch at the beginning. Not related to Jira/Plugin - just after a long pause in Java programming took time to master it again :)